# How to do text to column without replacing the original column

Tags: python, pandas

I have a text file which contains only one column and i want to do text to column for that column but don't want to replace the original column. I am able to do text to column only after assigning the 1st column manually in text file as '0' and not with the original column name "a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h,i,j,k,l,m,n,o,p,q,r,s,t,u,v,w,x,y,z". My code is as below:

```
import pandas as pd

df=pd.read_csv("oss1.txt",sep='\t',engine='python')

df['new']=df['0'].copy()

def text_to_column(df, col):
    df_detailed = df[col].str.rstrip(':| ').str.split(':| ', expand=True).astype(str)
    #replace columns names if necessary
    df_detailed.columns = df_detailed.columns.to_series().replace(":| ", ":| ")
    #remove column and join new df
    df_detailed = df.drop(col, axis=1).join(df_detailed)

    return df_detailed

df = text_to_column(df,'new')

df.to_excel("output_oss1.xlsx", index = False)
```

i/p

```
a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h,i,j,k,l,m,n,o,p,q,r,s,t,u,v,w,x,y,z
apple, boy,cat,dog,egg,fish,girl,hen,ink,jug,kite,lion,man,net,owl,pen,queen,rat,seat,ten,umbrella,va,watch,xmas,yak,zebra
1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22,23,24,25,26
```

o/p

```
a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h,i,j,k,l,m,n,o,p,q,r,s,t,u,v,w,x,y,z a   b   c   d   e   f   g   h   i   j   k   l   m   n   o   p   q   r   s   t   u   v   w   x   y   z
apple, boy,cat,dog,egg,fish,girl,hen,ink,jug,kite,lion,man,net,owl,pen,queen,rat,seat,ten,umbrella,va,watch,xmas,yak,zebra  apple   boy cat dog egg fish    girl    hen ink jug kite    lion    man net owl pen queen   rat seat    ten umbrella    van watch   xmas    yak zebra
1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22,23,24,25,26    1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8   9   10  11  12  13  14  15  16  17  18  19  20  21  22  23  24  25  26
```

- List item

Comment: `df['new']=df['0'].copy()` ?

Comment: after assigning 'new' and '0' value to the column it worked. But with this big name for column it is not working.

Comment: I can't parse this question. What is it that you want to do?

Comment: I want to do text to column using delimiter "," of the first column given in i/p but doesn't want the column to be replaced as shown in o/p

Comment: Perhaps consider not overwriting `df` and instead storing the information someplace else?

Answer (score 0):

One Way to Split Text in a column to multiple columns -

```
df.str.split(",", expand=True)
```

[Refer Documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.23/generated/pandas.Series.str.split.html#pandas-series-str-split)